# WordPress Admin Menu Order for 'admin.php' pages

Tags: admin, admin-menu, menu-order

I'm using following code to change menu order of WordPress admin panel.

```
function reorder_admin_menu( $__return_true ) {
    return array(
         'index.php', // Dashboard
         'separator1', // --Space--
         'edit.php?post_type=page', // Pages
         'edit.php', // Posts
         'edit.php?post_type=portfolio', // Portfolio
         'admin.php?page=wpcf7', // Contact Form 7
         'upload.php', // Media
         'edit-comments.php', // Comments
   );
}
add_filter( 'custom_menu_order', 'reorder_admin_menu' );
add_filter( 'menu_order', 'reorder_admin_menu' );
```

Now, it is working fine for WordPress default menu items (e.g. posts, pages, media etc). But it seems to be ignoring menu items having a slug of `admin.php?page=xxx`.

For example, I'm using `admin.php?page=wpcf7` for `Contact Form 7` plugin menu to put it above `Media` menu link but it is still getting positioned below `Media` and `Comments` menu link.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
return array(
     'index.php', // Dashboard
     'separator1', // --Space--
     'edit.php?post_type=page', // Pages
     'edit.php', // Posts
     'edit.php?post_type=portfolio', // Portfolio
     'admin.php?page=wpcf7', // Contact Form 7
     'upload.php', // Media
     'edit-comments.php', // Comments
   );
```

try this:

```
return array(
     'index.php', // Dashboard
     'separator1', // --Space--
     'edit.php?post_type=page', // Pages
     'edit.php', // Posts
     'portfolio', // Portfolio
     'wpcf7', // Contact Form 7
     'upload.php', // Media
     'edit-comments.php', // Comments
   );
```